# Groovier way to parse tsv file into map

Tags: groovy

I have a tsv file in the form of "key \t value", and I need to read into a map. Currently i do it like this:

```
referenceFile.eachLine { line ->
    def (name, reference) = line.split(/\t/)
    referencesMap[name.toLowerCase()] = reference
}
```

Is there a shorter/nicer way to do it?

Comment: IMO, this is a "code golf" question. This code is quite Groovy as it is. There may be ways to do it that are more clever, but not "nicer".

Comment: @MichaelEaster I don't agree - I think trying to find better ways to do a repeated task is a good way to improve your knowledge of the language

Comment: In general, that is true, but in this case, it is very hard to find anything better. Your time is better spent elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

It's already quite short. Two answers I can think of:

First one avoids the creation of a temporary map object:

```
referenceFile.inject([:]) { map, line ->
    def (name, reference) = line.split(/\t/)
    map[name.toLowerCase()] = reference
    map
}
```

Second one is more functional:

```
referenceFile.collect { it.split(/\t/) }.inject([:]) { map, val -> map[val[0].toLowerCase()] = val[1]; map }
```

Comment: Or `referenceFile.collect { it.tokenize( '\t' ) }.collectEntries { k, v -> [ k.toLowerCase(), v ] }` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The only other way I can think of doing it would be with an Iterator like you'd find in Commons IO:

```
@Grab( 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4' )
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

referencesMap = FileUtils.lineIterator( referenceFile, 'UTF-8' )
                         .collectEntries { line ->
  line.tokenize( '\t' ).with { k, v ->
    [ (k.toLowerCase()): v ]
  }
}
```

Or with a CSV parser:

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

referencesMap = referenceFile.withReader { r ->
  parseCsv( [ separator:'\t', readFirstLine:true ], r ).collectEntries {
    [ (it[ 0 ].toLowerCase()): it[ 1 ] ]
  }
}
```

But neither of them are shorter, and not necessarily nicer either...

Though I prefer option 2 as it can handle cases such as:

```
"key\twith\ttabs"\tvalue
```

As it deals with quoted strings

Answer (score 1):

This is the comment tim_yates added to melix's answer, and I think it's the shortest/clearest answer:

```
referenceFile.collect { it.tokenize( '\t' ) }.collectEntries { k, v -> [ k.toLowerCase(), v ] }
```

Comment: True, that's the shortest one but all answers except for the CSV parser one below will not handle quoted values or keys with tabs in them (see the comment in my answer), so whether it's the _"best"_ depends on your definition of best ;-)